# Variable length in strtok

Tags: c, strtok

I have seen some examples and tried to do something but now I am stuck.

The working code is

```
    char quality[5][10];
    char * qualities;
    qualities = strtok (message, "\n");
    int k = 0;
    while (qualities != NULL){
        if (k == 0) {
            strcpy(quality[0], qualities);
        }
        else if ( k == 1) {
            strcpy(quality[1], qualities);
        }
        else if ( k == 2) {
            strcpy(quality[2], qualities);
        }
        else if ( k == 3) {
            strcpy(quality[3], qualities);
        }
        else if ( k == 4) {
            strcpy(quality[4], qualities);
        }           
        qualities = strtok (NULL, "\n");
        k++;
    }
```

However this works with fixed length(in this case just 5), however I would like to assign a variable to quality variable but in that case while loop would not work. What should I do?

Comment: The whole `if (k == 1)` thing is pointless, just use `k` as the subscript, e.g. `quality[k]`.

Comment: Your quality array is quite small; it would be a good idea to check that the string (token) copied is small enough to fit OK.  With the revised code, you should also make sure that `k` stays with range too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this block

```
if (k == 0) {
        strcpy(quality[0], qualities);
} else if ( k == 1) {
    strcpy(quality[1], qualities);
} else if ( k == 2) {
    strcpy(quality[2], qualities);
} else if ( k == 3) {
    strcpy(quality[3], qualities);
} else if ( k == 4) {
    strcpy(quality[4], qualities);
}
qualities = strtok (NULL, "\n");
k++;
```

with these two lines:

```
strcpy(quality[k++], qualities);
qualities = strtok (NULL, "\n");
```

This is an equivalent code, but it will work with any number of items, up to the number of elements in the `quality` array.

Since the number of elements is fixed, you should change

```
while (qualities != NULL)
```

to

```
while (k < N && qualities != NULL)
```

where `N` is the number of elements in `qualities`.

Comment: You should really ensure no overflows — check that `k` is in range (0..4) and that the token length is small enough (`strlen(qualities) < 10`).

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to effectively mimic your current loop (but with a dynamic length) using the following code:

```
while (qualities != NULL){
    if(k<sizeOfYouArray)
        strcpy(quality[k], qualities);           
    qualities = strtok (NULL, "\n");
    k++;
}
```

Essentially, instead of checking each individual value of `k` and acting accordingly, the loop should just continue to call `strcpy` until `k` is greater than `sizeOfYourArray` (similarly to how your current code would act if `sizeOfYourArray` was set to 5- `strcopy` would no longer be called).

This may not be the most effective or efficient solution for your program in the long run (a `for` loop may function better, if I understand your code correctly), but that would be the minimum required change.

Comment: You should really ensure no overflows — check that `k` is in range (0..4) and that the token length is small enough (`strlen(qualities) < 10`).